# vue.js, simple v-for / v-bind to add index to class name

Tags: vue.js

I can't seem to find the syntax to loop through my items and give each 'li' a class corresponding to the index.  How is this done?

```
<li v-for="(item, idx) in items class="idx"">
</li>
```

Comment: You want `:class`, not `class`. And you want to fix your `"` mark placement.

Comment: That doesn't work though..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this would be most readable (added a prefix because a class can't start with a number).

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="[`index--${index}`]"></li>
```

Also using an array because this always looked off to me.

```
:class="`index--${index}`"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to swap `item` and `index`: `v-for="(index, item) in items"`.

Comment: It used to be that in Vue 1, it has been this order since Vue 2.

Comment: I'm using Vue 1, if it matters. Vue 1 docs for `v-for` offers `(index, item)` syntax too http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for